# three.js switch materials as camaro materials

Tags: function, three.js, switch-statement, textures

I test the material switch on three.js and I have seen material camaro ici :
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cars_camaro.html

But if I think understand the code, I tried to reproduce it with a single object that has a single material
and clicking on the button changes the material.
But I have two problems:
- How to create a variation of material with a texture
- After 3 days of testing, my code does not work and I do not understand why
if you could tell me where it gets stuck and why:

```
/////////////////////// MATERIAL /////////////////////////////
var materials = {

Red: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0x660000,
    envMap: textureCube,
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,
    reflectivity: 0.5
    } ),

Black: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0x000000,
    envMap: textureCube,
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,
    reflectivity: 0.5
    } ),

White: new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    envMap: textureCube,
    combine: THREE.MixOperation,
    reflectivity: 0.5
    } ),

Gold: new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xaa9944,
    specular: 0xbbaa99,
    shininess: 50,
    envMap: textureCube,
    combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation
    } ),

Chrome: new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    specular:0xffffff,
    envMap: textureCube,
    combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation
    } ),
// how to configure this material ?             
/*LWood: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ( texture );
    url = "models/macabann/chataigner.jpg";
    imgTexture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
    imgTexture.wrapS = imgTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    imgTexture.anisotropy = 16;
    shininess: 50;
    specular: 0x333333;
    envMap: textureCube;
    combine: THREE.MixOperation;
    reflectivity: 0.2;
    bumpScale: 1; 
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading;*/

/*DWood: new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture ( texture );
    url = "models/macabann/chataigner.jpg";
    imgTexture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
    imgTexture.wrapS = imgTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    imgTexture.anisotropy = 16;
    shininess: 50;
    specular: 0x333333;
    envMap: textureCube;
    combine: THREE.MixOperation;
    reflectivity: 0.2;
    bumpScale: 0; 
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading;*/

};

/////////////////////// FIN MATERIAL /////////////////////////////

////////////////////////// OBJET ////////////////////////////


var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('models/macabann/bielo.js', function ( geometry )
    { createScene( geometry, materials ) } 
);

function createScene( geometry, materials ) {
var Bmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
Bmaterial  = materials [ "Orange" ];// default cette ligne merde

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, Bmaterial );
    mesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    mesh.position.y = 0;
    mesh.position.x = 0;
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

            scene.add( mesh );

            createButtons( materials, Bmaterial );

}

///////////////////// FIN OBJET ///////////////////////

//////////////////// buttons //////////////////////////
function createButtons( materials, Bmaterial ) {
var buttons = document.getElementById( "buttons" );
for ( var key in materials ) {
    var button = document.createElement( 'button' );
    button.textContent = key;
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
        Bmaterial = materials[ this.textContent ];///////problem ?
    }, false 
    );
    buttons.appendChild( button );

}

}
```

thanks to answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is incorrect

```
function createScene( geometry, materials ) {
    var m = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
    m.materials  = Bmaterial [ "Orange" ];

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, m );
```

It should be

```
function createScene( geometry, materials ) {
    var m = Bmaterial [ "Orange" ];

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, m );
```

Also, you can't change from a less complicated material to a more complicated one. For example, if one material has a texture, they all must. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates.

So make all your materials in you material array `MeshPhongMaterial`. If one material does not need a texture, then assign it a dummy white one.

Comment: Thank to answer...for this I found the solution this night. The objet and default material are good.... my buttons take the good name but when I clic, the object doesn't take the new material...If I understand you, it's not possible to apply a material or a texture in the same page ?

Comment: What you are trying to do should work with my suggestions. If it is not working, provide a link to a live example of your code. Be sure to use three.js r.54.

Comment: OK, here is working code: http://pastebin.com/990mi6td. I removed part of the code so I could get my arms around it. You will have to reset the original file paths. Please remember to accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: thank a lot. it's okey with three.js - for info I tested with three.min.js and the texture skybox is not displaying. I learned a lot there, but is that it means that the code examples are obsolete?

Comment: I took the skybox out to simplify your code so I could understand it more easily. You can put the skybox back in if you want to -- but learn from the three.js official examples, not from old examples from the net. Good luck!

Comment: yes I have seen. I have understood you have taken off the skybox but it's only the skybox textures which don't display with the three.min.js then they are displaying with three.js...it's for info only...

Comment: Both three.js and three.min.js should produce the same result. Make sure you are using identical versions.